# scope of a variable in java in switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I am trying to understand how this is valid in case statement of a switch in Java.

```
switch(someValue){
    case abc: int i=0
    break;
    case def: int i=0 // error because i declared above is still accessible in this case.`
```

If we say that variables have a block scope in Java , shouldn't the "i" variable be inaccessible in the case of def? Or is the case not treated as a block ?
Many people must have come across this problem before.

Why does this not violate any fundamental concepts of programming?

Comment: The `switch` defines a block, not the `case`.

Comment: ohhk got u thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the block is what follows the switch statement, not each case within it:

```
switch (...) { // start of block
  case: ...
  break;
  ...
} // end of block
```

Writing `break` doesn't put an end to the block when it's used in a `for` loop; likewise, writing `case` doesn't begin a new block when it's used in a `switch`. It might help to think of them as labels to jump to within the block.

If you want to reuse the variable, you might define it within a block after your case:

```
case abc: {int i=0 ...}
  break;
```